# Trying to execute a shell script gives error "./: is a directory"

Tags: scripts, directory

I did the `chmod +x` to the file, but it still won't run the script, and I have no idea what's wrong with it:

```
~$ chmod +x hworld.sh
~$ ./ hworld.sh
-bash: ./: Is a directory
```

Comment: Please provide a proper problem description. What did you do, what was the expected result, what was the actual result? Please provide info in text form in your question, not as a link to an image.

Comment: Hello. Two things first do not post pictures of text include the text in the body of the question. Also there is nothing here that can be used to help you. You need to have a clear question that says what is wrong, what you did to try and fix it and what errors you got.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no space in between `./` and the script name.

Instead of this:

```
./ hworld.sh
```

Run this instead:

```
./hworld.sh
```

To explain, `./` is a shortened path to your current directory. This file is in your current directory so the forward slash needs to be directly before the file name with no space in between.